# VBA - Excel - Resetting var macro

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you are doing well. 
I wrote a macro for saving the active workbook with the date and hour. Everything work fine except the hour, date are not resetting after I re run the code.

Here is the code:

```
Sub SaveFile()

Dim fname As String
Dim fdate As String
Dim fhour As String
Dim name As String
Dim name2 As String
Dim path As String
Dim f_name As String
Dim f_date As String
Dim f_hour As String
Dim n_ame As String
Dim n_ame2 As String
Dim p_ath As String

On Error GoTo First
fdate = Format(Date, "yyyy") & " " & Format(Date, "mm") & " " & Format(Date, "dd")
fhour = Format(Time, "hh") & "h" & Format(Time, "mm")
name = Left(ThisWorkbook.name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.name, "_", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
fname = name & "_" & fdate & " - " & fhour
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\" & fname, _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Exit Sub

First:

On Error GoTo -1
On Error GoTo Second
fdate = Format(Date, "yyyy") & " " & Format(Date, "mm") & " " & Format(Date, "dd")
fhour = Format(Time, "hh") & "h" & Format(Time, "mm")
name = Left(ThisWorkbook.name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.name, "_", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
fname = name & "_" & fdate & " - " & fhour
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\" & fname, _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Exit Sub

Second:
f_date = Format(Date, "yyyy") & " " & Format(Date, "mm") & " " & Format(Date, "dd")
f_hour = Format(Time, "hh") & "h" & Format(Time, "mm")
n_ame = Left(ThisWorkbook.name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
f_name = n_ame & "_" & f_date & " - " & f_hour
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\" & f_name, _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

The macro currently save for the first time in the wanted format and for the next time will understand and left the correct number of characters to save in the proper wanted format.
I also set a "second chance" in case of too early enter pressed.

Currently if my workbook is name "Workook"
The macro will save it as "Workbook_2019 10 14 - 19h12" and not the current time and date values.

Thanks for your help
Naxos

Comment: Please review this reference http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm - in particular around what you can do (and can't do) once you're in an error handler block

Comment: You can shorten up all the date formatting into one statement: `fname = Name & Format(Now, "_yyyy mm dd - hh\hmm")`

Comment: Also, you're mixing the use of `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`. Don't do that. Pick one and stick with it. The recommended use is almost always `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally based on your advice I made the code simpler and everything work now.
I post it for the next users

```
Private Sub SaveFile()
Dim fname As String
Dim fdate As String
Dim fhour As String
Dim name As String
Dim name2 As String
Dim path As String
Dim f_name As String
Dim ppfdate As String
Dim ppfhour As String
Dim ppfname As String
Dim ppfname2 As String
Dim pppath As String

dateactuelle = Now()

On Error GoTo First
fdate = Format(dateactuelle, "yyyymmdd - h\hmm")
name = Left(ActiveWorkbook.name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.name, "_", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
fname = name & "_v" & fdate

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & "\" & fname, _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Exit Sub

First:
ppfdate = Format(dateactuelle, "yyyymmdd - h\hmm")
ppfname = Left(ActiveWorkbook.name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
f_name = ppfname & "_v" & ppfdate

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & "\" & f_name, _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```